# excel conditional format not showing in format cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a conditional format which is working an filling the back ground with the right color in the cell, but when i go to inpect the cell with format cell and click on fill it shows that there is no Fill any idea why this would be.

is there away that i can count the color that the consitional format has set using VBA.

currently using tyhe code below and it fails at the color index line.

```
Function CountRed(MyRange As Range)
CountRed = 0
For Each cell In MyRange
ColorIndex = cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex

If ColorIndex = 43 Then
CountRed = CountRed + 1
End If


Next cell
test = 0

End Function
```

Comment: because there is no fill, there is conditional formatting

Comment: for Excel 2010+ [Range.DisplayFormat Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838814(v=office.15).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code below will go through each of the conditional formatted exterior color and then will color the cell with a RGB color specified,

```
Dim MyRange As Range
Set MyRange = Range("F2:J17")

Dim rng As Range

For Each rng In MyRange

If rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then

    rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

End If

If rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 44 Then

    rng.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)

End If
If rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex = 43 Then

    rng.Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)

End If



Next rng
```

Answer (score 0):

As simoco pointed out in the comments, you can achieve this via `Range.DisplayFormat`

Do something like

```
MsgBox Range("A1").DisplayFormat.Interior.ColorIndex
```

to get the currently displayed background-color of the cell.